# How can I chain directives together in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a table with rows that end up looking something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><my-dir-1></my-dir-1></td>
    <td><my-dir-1></my-dir-1></td>
    <td><my-dir-2></my-dir-2></td>
    <td><my-dir-1></my-dir-1></td>
    <td><my-dir-1></my-dir-1></td>
    <td><my-dir-3></my-dir-3></td>
    <td><my-dir-1></my-dir-1></td>
</tr>
```

At certain times I need the first column to execute its someFn() function, then tell the next column to do the same. Imagine the directives looking like this:

```
angular.module('MyModule').directive('myDir1', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.someFn = function() { //logic };
        }
    }
}]);
angular.module('MyModule').directive('myDir2', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.someFn = function() { //logic };
        }
    }
}]);
```

I tried using `scope.$$nextSibling`, but this only seems to return the next sibling of the SAME type of directive. i.e., in the example above, it goes through all `my-dir-1` columns, but skips over `my-dir-2` and `my-dir-3`. Is there a way to chain these together so this example would work?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't communicate between sibling directives like that.  It can get messy.  The best way to communicate between them is either

1) Through a parent directives controller

So your top level `<tr>` element could be it's own directive.  Add a `requires` statement to `myDir1` and `myDir2` definition objects and then communicate through the parent controller

2) Through a service.

Have a service that both directives can inject and let it handle the shared logic/dependency resolution